# What is the Big-O complexity of this method?

Tags: recursion, big-o, time-complexity

How do we find the BigO run time for the following recursive function?

```
public int foo(int x,int k) { 
 if (x <= k)
   return 1; 
 else
   return foo(x / k, k) + 1;
}
```

Comment: People like me go to your profile, and see that you dont have any accepted answer for your question, and we think why should we answer some one like yours question?!

Answer (score 0):

Look at what it's doing and ask yourself:

- How many times does one call to the method call itself?
- What happens to the parameters to make it terminate?

BTW, do you mean for your `x` to be an `int`? What if `x == 1 and k == 2`? `x/k` is zero using [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: If x==1 and k==2 then x<k, so it returns 1.

Comment: I chose my example poorly. What about 7 and 3? `(int)7/(int)3 == 2`.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with x being int, I dont see the point!